# In Advaita, what happens to the subtle body after videha-mukti?

Tags: advaita

According to Advaita, what happens to the subtle body after videha mukti? Does Shankara or the Upanishads says anything about it?

Comment: It use to continue till the end of prarabdha. Yoga-Vasista mentions it in greater detail.

Comment: Mention the verse please. And also the name of translator.

Comment: Hanugm,  person is asking what happens after Videha mukti I.e after all karmas expire

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if Shankara or the Upanishads say anything about it. Garuda Purana says that a person who attains liberation gets rid of the subtle body.

> The river Viraja, forms the eighth enclosure. It flows in between the
> spaces of ether. It spreads over five yojanas all round.
>
> It is the most sacred river that wards of rebirth. O bird, those who
> bathe herein go to Brahmaloka where they rejoice with the four-faced
> Brahma.
>
> **Those who take the bath in the Viraja river abandon their subtle
> bodies and attain liberation.**
>
> Those alone who have realized the Self and abide in Brahman can cross
> the Viraja river.

**Garuda Purana, Brahma(Moksha) Khanda, Chapter X**

Answer (score 0):

On Jeevan Mukti, Karana Shareera gets destroyed, but Sthula and Sookshma shareera is retained till prarabdha is there.

On Videha Mukti, both Sthoola and Sookshma shareera gets destroyed.

Comment: Please quote from the scriptures.

Comment: you need to give references, otherwise you are stating your opinion, and opinions should be done as comments, not as an answer.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Swamiji I had heard it somewhere. I am trying to remember